# smbclient fails with message 'protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES', what does it mean and how to fix it?

Tags: samba

I'm trying to access a Windows share with smbclient and I'm getting this NT_STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error, regardless of correct or incorrect credentials.

The command was about listing the shares:

```
smbclient -L //computer.domain -U domain/username
```

It asks for password but fails after it.

If try to open a share on it the same happens:

```
smbclient //computer.domain/sharename -U domain/username
```

I looked around the web and found nothing relevant. Other Samba clients fail with similar meaningless error messages.

I can access the share from Windows 7.

I can also access other shares from Linux, except the ones stored on that particular computer.

So how can I access this problematic Windows share with smbclient? Is it possible? If not, are there workarounds?

(I'm using an Ubuntu Server 12.04)

Comment: Please post your `smb.conf`

Answer (score 6):

### Problem

In the client

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o uid=user,gid=user,username=user,password=password //192.168.0.100/shared /mnt/smb
mount: Cannot allocate memory

smbclient -L pc -U user%password
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

dmesg | tail
…
[49474.230547] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -12
```

### Solution

Restarting `LanmanServer` can solve the problem

In the server

```
net stop LanmanServer /y && net start LanmanServer
These workstations have sessions on this server:

192.168.0.100
These workstations have sessions with open files on this server:

192.168.0.100
The following services are dependent on the Server service.
Stopping the Server service will also stop these services.

   HomeGroup Listener
   Computer Browser

The HomeGroup Listener service is stopping.
The HomeGroup Listener service was stopped successfully.

The Computer Browser service is stopping..
The Computer Browser service was stopped successfully.

The Server service is stopping.
The Server service was stopped successfully.

The Server service is starting.
The Server service was started successfully.
```

```
net start Browser
The requested service has already been started.
```

```
net start HomeGroupListener
The HomeGroup Listener service is starting.
The HomeGroup Listener service was started successfully.
```

After this `smbclient` in the client doesn't return an error

```
smbclient -L pc -U user%password
Domain=[PC] OS=[Windows 7 Ultimate 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows 7 Ultimate 6.1]
…
```

### Client

The client is

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 13.04 \n \l

sudo dmidecode | grep -A2 "Base Board"
   Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
   Product Name: 440BX Desktop Reference Platform
```

### Server

The server is

```
ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

dmidecode | grep -A2 "Base Board"
   Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
   Product Name: P8Z77-M PRO
```